# How to do non-obtrusive number-crunching on mysql db?

Tags: mysql, multithreading, mariadb, database-performance

Not sure how to state this question.

I have a very busy DB in production with close to 1 million hits daily.

Now I would like to do some research on the real-time data (**edit:** "real-time" can be a few minutes old).

**What is the best way to do this without interrupting production?**

Ideas:

1. in the unix shell, there is the `nice` concept. It lets me give a low priority to a specific thread so it only uses CPU when the other threads are idle. I am basically looking for the same in a mysql context.
2. Get a DB dump and do the research offline:

   - Doesn't that take down my site for the several minutes it takes to get the dump?
   - Is there a way to configure the dump command so it does the extraction in a `nice` way (see above)?
3. Do the SQL commands directly on the live DB:

   - Is there a way, again, to configure the commands so they are executed in a `nice` way?

**Update:** What are the arguments against Idea 2?

Comment: Maybe DB replication could be usefull in this case. You can do the extraction on the second DB without impacting the one in production

Comment: What kinds of hits are they?  What Engine?  What type of disk (SSD or not)?  Is the table small enough to be cached in RAM?  What does your 'dangerous' query look like?  There are many situations in which I would not be afraid to run a query in production.  But answer these questions to see if you have a worse situation.

Comment: The "hits" are the execution of my PHP site. Most of the hits do a few lookups and a few writes on tables that are up to 6 GB large. There is no "dangerous" query. The only "dangerous" situation I can imagine is that during this exploration I'd come up with ideas that require queries over columns that are not indexed etc. I work in a shared hosting environment and am not sure about the hardware.

Comment: For dumping, look into Percona Toolkit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments on StackOverflow and in-person discussions, here's an answer for whoever gets here with the same question:

- In MySQL, there seems not to be any `nice` type control over prioritization of processes (I hear there is in Oracle, for example)
- Since any "number-crunching" is at most treated like one more visitor to my website, it won't take down the site performance-wise. So it can safely be run in production (read-only, of course...).